# Retorno com array em json mostrando apenas primeiro registro

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php
    //database configuration
    $dbHost     = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName     = 'master';

//connect with the database
$Mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

$arr = array();


//get matched data from skills table
if(empty($erro)){
    $query = "SELECT 
    r.endereco_cep        AS CEP,
    r.endereco_logradouro AS ENDERECO, 
    b.bairro_descricao    AS BAIRRO,
    c.cidade_codigo       AS CODCID,
    c.cidade_descricao    AS CIDADE,
    e.uf_sigla            AS SIGLA,
    e.uf_descricao        AS ESTADO
    FROM 
    cep_endereco AS r
    LEFT JOIN cep_bairro AS b ON b.bairro_codigo = r.bairro_codigo
    LEFT JOIN cep_cidade AS c ON c.cidade_codigo = b.cidade_codigo
    LEFT JOIN cep_uf     AS e ON e.uf_codigo = c.uf_codigo   
    WHERE 
    c.cidade_codigo = '3169'";
         $result = $Mysqli->query($query);

         if($result->num_rows > 0){

            $obj = $result->fetch_object();

            $arr['result'] = true;
            $arr['dados']['endereco']= $obj->ENDERECO;



         }else{
            $arr['result'] = false;
            $arr['msg'] = "USUARIO INCORRETO";
         }
      }else{
         $arr['result'] = false;
         $arr['msg'] = $erro;
      }

     echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Na query acima a intenção é retornar todos os endereços em um json,mais esta retornando apenas o primeiro, como poderia retornar todos ?

> Retorno atual:

```
{"result":true,"dados":{"endereco":"RUA ABEL COUTO"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou vc colocar o: `$obj = $result->fetch_object()` dentro de um laço para percorrer todos os registros do `select`. Também adicionei o array resultado para receber todos os resultados.

```
  <?php
    //database configuration
    $dbHost     = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName     = 'master';

//connect with the database
$Mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

$arr = array();
$resultado = array();


//get matched data from skills table
if(empty($erro)){
    $query = "SELECT 
    r.endereco_cep        AS CEP,
    r.endereco_logradouro AS ENDERECO, 
    b.bairro_descricao    AS BAIRRO,
    c.cidade_codigo       AS CODCID,
    c.cidade_descricao    AS CIDADE,
    e.uf_sigla            AS SIGLA,
    e.uf_descricao        AS ESTADO
    FROM 
    cep_endereco AS r
    LEFT JOIN cep_bairro AS b ON b.bairro_codigo = r.bairro_codigo
    LEFT JOIN cep_cidade AS c ON c.cidade_codigo = b.cidade_codigo
    LEFT JOIN cep_uf     AS e ON e.uf_codigo = c.uf_codigo   
    WHERE 
    c.cidade_codigo = '3169'";
         $result = $Mysqli->query($query);

         if($result->num_rows > 0){

            while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()){

               $arr['result'] = true;
               $arr['dados']['endereco']= $obj->ENDERECO;
               $resultado[] = $arr;
            }

         }else{
            $arr['result'] = false;
            $arr['msg'] = "USUARIO INCORRETO";
            $resultado[] = $arr;
         }
      }else{
         $arr['result'] = false;
         $arr['msg'] = $erro;
         $resultado[] = $arr;
      }

     echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Comment: Só no php não esta retornando nada na tela, mais se eu dou um var_dump($resultado); ele tem os resultados,estranho, ta faltando algo minimo

Comment: Se vc acessar essa página php no navegador ela fica em branco?

Comment: sim,mais se no php eu incluir o var_dump($resultado); ele retorna: array(1873) { [0]=> array(2) { ["result"]=> bool(true) ["dados"]=> array(1) { ["endereco"]=> string(14) "RUA ABEL COUTO" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["result"]=> bool(true) ["dados"]=> array(1) { ["endereco"]=> string(15) "RUA DAS ACÁCIAS" } } .....

Comment: sim pq resultado é um array ai fica dessa forma. Ai qnd vc usa o `echo json_encode($resultado);` ele transforma o array para json. Mas era para mostrar o json na página php.

Comment: Resolvido: coloquei o json dentro do seu while

Comment: Complementei a sua resposta

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $obj = $result->fetch_object();
    $arr['result'] = true;
    $arr['dados']['endereco']= $obj->ENDERECO;
}else{
    $arr['result'] = false;
    $arr['msg'] = "USUARIO INCORRETO";
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

---

No seu código, o loop está fazendo o mesmo que :

```
$arr['dados']['endereco']= 'endereco 1';
$arr['dados']['endereco']= 'endereco 2';
$arr['dados']['endereco']= 'endereco 3';
```

Ou seja, sempre está sobrepondo a ultima chave. O seu output `{"result":true,"dados":{"endereco":"RUA ABEL COUTO"}}` corresponde a ultima linha do loop

---

Você precisa fazer um array da seguinte forma no seu loop:

```
$arr[]['result'] = true;
$arr[]['dados']['endereco']= $obj->ENDERECO;
```

**O output final seria:**

```
$arr[0]['dados']['endereco']= 'endereco 1';
$arr[1]['dados']['endereco']= 'endereco 2';
$arr[2]['dados']['endereco']= 'endereco 3';
```

Comment: Aconteceu da mesma forma da ajuda da @Jessika no php não esta retornando nada na tela, mais se eu dou um var_dump($resultado); ou no seu caso var_dump($arr);  ele tem os resultados