# Json.parse não converte para array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, postgresql

Olá, sou um amador completo em php e javascript e após um mês de peleja com duas linguagens que eu nunca tinha mexido cheguei até aqui.

Estou tentando passar um JSON de uma requisição de volta para array no meu javascript, mas quando uso o parse e imprimo no console o typeof da variável ela continua como string e não como array. Vou deixar abaixo os códigos e o que apareceu no console, junto com mais informações.

Código PHP:

```
<?php

    include("conexao_postgres.php");

    $ano_base = $_POST["ano_ref"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.parametros_estaduais WHERE ano_base = $ano_base";
    $resultado = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
    $resultado_array = pg_fetch_row($resultado);

    echo json_encode($resultado_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

Para agilizar e facilitar, eu repliquei a query com o teste que eu to fazendo no código principal pra saber mais rápido o que está acontecendo no PHP. O que vem do echo é isso daqui:

JSON>> **[2016,0.02,347.58,528.51,902.93,1574.08,1745,880,396.49,14,152.84,207,0.35,20]**

Na minha última dúvida me perguntaram isso, então já adianto, pg_query retorna um resourse de consulta ao BD e pg_fetch_row (eu sei que tem o método que linka os nomes das colunas da table, mas ai eu iria trabalhar com um obj e prefiro trabalhar com o array q é mais direto, e sim, já testei usando o pg_fetch_assoc e ele n converte em um obj, continua como string também e não da erro no JSON.parse em nenhum dos dois) retorna uma linha de consulta do resourse como um array.

Trecho de código do request:

```
$.post("query.php", {ano_ref: ano_base},
    function(retorno){
        var resposta = JSON.stringify(retorno);
        console.log("Data retorno: " + retorno + "Data resposta: " + resposta + "É uma string? " + typeof resposta);
        var vetor = JSON.parse(resposta);
        console.log("Data retorno: " + retorno + "Data vetor: " + vetor + "É um array? " + typeof vetor);
});
```

Os resultados do console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que ta uma bagunça, mas foi o que deu pra fazer até agora. Tem uns \n \t e \s dps que executa o stringfy que eu não tenho ideia de onde saiu. Imagino que talvez seja daí o erro. Outro detalhe, eu testei converter a string que vem do request na mão, colocando em uma string e fazendo o mesmo processo, e funciona, o que me leva a concluir que o formato do JSON que vem não tem problemas, eu copiei e colei direto da página (tem o msm trecho php no código principal, como eu disse pra facilitar eu ver o que tava acontecendo).

Sugestão dos comentários*:

```
<?php

    include("conexao_postgres.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.parametros_estaduais WHERE ano_base = 2016";
    $resultado = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
    $resultado_array = pg_fetch_row($resultado);

    //echo json_encode($resultado_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $json = array();
    for($i=0; $i < count($resultado_array); $i++){
        $json[$i] = $resultado_array[$i];
    }
    echo(json_encode($json, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
?>
```

Comment: Já validou seu Json aqui? https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Acabei de validar, ta certinho. Como eu disse, eu fiz uma string com ele na mão e usei os stringfy e parse pra testar se o problema era no formato do json, mas ele converteu certinho pra array. O problema aparentemente não é no [2016,0.02,347.58,528.51,902.93,1574.08,1745,880,396.49,14,152.84,207,0.35,20]

Comment: Posta seu Json em vez de imagem @Állan!

Comment: Coloquei em negrito ali na descrição pra ficar mais claro, é exatamente aquilo @Marconi

Comment: Veja, funciona certinho. https://jsfiddle.net/b0u750L1/

Comment: Foi exatamente esse teste o que eu fiz, se vc cria uma string e faz isso, funciona, mas no meu código não. Entendeu o meu dilema? da uma conferida na imagem do console. Vc vai reparar que eu dou um stringfy do resultado para a resposta, ele converte o undefined pra string (com vários \t \n \r que não sei de onde veio) e depois eu dou um parse para vetor, mas ele não converte pro array e também não da erro no console. Inclusive eu coloquei um alert(vetor[0]) que deveria imprimir "2016", mas imprime em branco.

Comment: Troca o: `JSON.stringify` por: `JSON.parse`

Comment: O primeiro código que fiz tava assim. Se eu não dou stringfy ele da: 
unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
pelo que entendo é pq retorno é typeof undefined

Comment: Tenta gerar o json no php, em vez de pegar o resultado do `select`. Tipo assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197484/retorno-com-array-em-json-mostrando-apenas-primeiro-registro/197493#197493

Comment: @Jessika editei e coloquei no final o que entendi do que você me sugeriu. Espero que tenha entendido certo. Se for, o problema continua

Comment: Coloca o nome das colunas q vc está utilizando no select q eu vou tentar te ajudar

Comment: Eu pego todas, mas tenho uma forte intuição que o erro é no stringfy.

"SELECT ano_base, ipva_mensal, preco_pneu_veiculo1, preco_pneu_veiculo2, preco_pneu_veiculo3, preco_pneu_veiculo4, salario_motorista, 
  salario_acompanhante, seguro_obrigatorio, imposto_sindical_pf, imposto_sindical_pj, dias_letivos_ano, adicional_estrada_terra, dias_mes
  FROM public.parametros_estaduais WHERE ano_base = $ano_base";

Comment: Tenta tirar os escapes com `replace`, aq tem um exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript   depois da um `json.parse` na string e ve se gera seu objeto

Comment: Consegui solucionar, apaguei td e usei eval, como mágica funcionou. Agora só preciso fechar os detalhes, muito obrigado pela ajuda @Jessika.

Answer (score 1):

Problema solucionado da seguinte forma:

```
$.post("query.php", {ano_ref: ano_base},
    function(retorno){
        // Decodificando JSON para object/array
        var dados = eval('(' + retorno.toString() + ')');
        tratarDados(dados);
});
```