# Loop em json que retorne todos os registros

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, nele faço uma busca com ajax e ela retorna um *json* com os registros do banco, mas não consegui elaborar um *loop* no **PHP** para que o *json* conseguisse retornar todos os registros. Abaixo segue meu código:

exibir.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-sm-1 control-label">Filtro</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control m-b-10" name="id" charset="utf-8" onchange="busca();">
            <option>Selecione</option>
           <?php
            $select  = "SELECT * FROM pessoas"; 
            $result  = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);
            while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $id = $exibe['id'];
                echo '<option  charset="utf-8" value = '. $id . '>' . utf8_encode(strtolower($exibe['nome'])) . '</option>';
            }                                    
            mysqli_free_result($result); 
           ?>                                                                          
        </select> 
    </div>                                                         
</div>        
<div class="col-md-8">
    <label class="col-sm-8 col-sm-8 control-label" style="display: none;" id="vazio">Não foram encontrados resultados!</label>
</div>                                                                                             
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="tabela">
        <thead id="top">
        </thead>
<script>
  function busca(){
    var id         = document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value;
    var parametros = {
      method: "GET"
    };
    fetch("php/busca.php?id=" + id, parametros).then(function(resposta) {
      return resposta.json();
    }).then(function(retorno){
        console.log(retorno);                 
        if (retorno != 1){   
          document.getElementById("vazio").style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById("top").style.display = 'none'; 
          document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML      = "<thead><tbody><tr><th>Nome</th><tr><td>" + retorno.nome + "</td></tr></tbody></thead>";                                
        }else{
          document.getElementById("vazio").style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    });            
  }
</script>
```

busca.php

```
header('Content-Type: json/application'); 
$id      = $_GET['id'];
$select  = "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE ent_id = '$id'";
$resul   = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);

if ((mysqli_num_rows($resul) > 0)) {
    $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul);
    echo json_encode($mostrar);
}else{
    $mostrar = 1;
    echo json_encode($mostrar);
}
```

Comment: Qual é o resultado obtido com o código atual?

Comment: O json retorna apenas a primeira linha, pois não fiz um loop na associação dos dados.

Comment: Mas você fez o `select` pelo id, é natural que seja retornado apenas um registro.

Comment: Existem mais registros relacionados a um mesmo id. Neste site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197484/retorno-com-array-em-json-mostrando-apenas-primeiro-registro tem um exemplo de como fazer esse loop, porém não entendi como colocar no meu código de maneira que funcione.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No busca.php, você só está a retornar o primeiro resultado. Tem de fazer em loop como faz para as options do select e criar um array (optei por criar só com o nome, pois no javascript só estavas a usar o nome e assim sempre são menos dados para transferir):

```
header('Content-Type: json/application'); 
$id      = $_GET['id'];
$select  = "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE ent_id = '$id'";
$resul   = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);

$dados = array();
if ((mysqli_num_rows($resul) > 0)) {
    while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul)){
         $dados[] = $mostrar['nome'];
    }                                    
    mysqli_free_result($resul); 
    echo json_encode($dados);
}else{
    $mostrar = 1;
    echo json_encode($mostrar);
}
```

Depois no ajax, tem de fazer um outro loop.

```
<script>
  function busca(){
    var id         = document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value;
    var parametros = {
      method: "GET"
    };
    fetch("php/busca.php?id=" + id, parametros).then(function(resposta) {
      return resposta.json();
    }).then(function(retorno){
        console.log(retorno);                 
        if (retorno != 1){   
          document.getElementById("vazio").style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById("top").style.display = 'none'; 
          var tabela = "<thead><tbody><tr><th>Nome</th></tr>";
          var arrayLength = retorno.length;
          var c = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                if(c == 0)
                    tabela += "<tr><td>";
                tabela += retorno[i] + " ";
                if((c == 6) || (i == (arrayLength - 1))){
                    tabela += "</td></tr>";
                    c = 0;
                }
                else
                    c++;
          }
          tabela += "</thead>";
          document.getElementyById("tabela").innerHTML = tabela;                                
        }else{
          document.getElementById("vazio").style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    });            
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, isso funciona. Mas eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer para a cada 7 campos dar um `<br>`, algo assim. Outro problema é que tem campos que preciso tratar de maneira diferente, mas não sei como encontrá-los, já que é feito loop

Comment: já alterei, a cada 7 linhas, acrescenta mais uma vazia.

Comment: Não funcionou assim, pois eu exibo os campos um ao lado do outro, como em uma tabela, o array vai de 0 a 6, eu preciso que após esse último, os próximos registros pulem pra próxima linha, literalmente um `<br>`

Comment: Alterei para ter o br, mas não entendi se queres com os elementos da tabela (td, tr, etc...) ou não. ou queres todos sem ter os td antes e depois de cada nome?

Comment: Eu preciso que quando chegar no registro 6, crie uma nova `<tr>` para inserir os próximos registros, porque ao implementar seu código eu alterei um pouco, pois não ficava como eu queria separarando cada registro por `<tr>`, mas sim por apenas `<td>`.

Comment: Já alterei. Não testei, mas deve só fechar a tr ao fim de 6 ou no ultimo elemento e abrir outra tr se for necessário.

Comment: Como fica o JSON retornado?

Comment: O código atual está fazendo o que é necessário, a cada 7 <td>, um </tr> é colocado para pular a linha.